# Once I have saved data to a variable, how can I then use that variable to copy to a new file?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that is retrieving data to an array variable in a ForEach loop. I'd like to next use this array variable and save this array data into a new file (JSON or CSV is preferred).

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a ForEach loop and We can use the `item().<KeyName>` to access every item's value.

For exmaple :
If the file is formatted as the following: {"id":"ba3cbfdd-c668-4dab-88c0-ac2f3af183cf"} {"id":"e90f527b-efe0-43ee-b398-e9e6b7f2abb5"}, then we can use `item().id` to access the value.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in on this one Joseph. I am thinking now I will need a more sustainable solution for this.

In my ForEach loop, I run a Set Var (with @item() as the Item) and then a Copy Data. I am not sure if this is the best approach. What I ideally want to do, is iterate through a list of data in Source, and run a ForEach to iterate through each item in the list a run a Copy Data to another source.

In summary, take array source A of "IDs", iterate through each "ID of Source A, and run a Copy Data for each ID to retrieve new data to build-up (not sure if possible..) Sink file B.

Comment: What's your data type to retrieve? Is it SQL?

Comment: I am retrieving a JSON file that I've transformed and created by a dataflow. It's just a list of ID records, so I am not sure if they are compatible with further automation steps as the file is formatted (exactly) as the following:
{"id":"ba3cbfdd-c668-4dab-88c0-ac2f3af183cf"}
{"id":"e90f527b-efe0-43ee-b398-e9e6b7f2abb5"} (repeat new lines for each ID returned)

Comment: I have tried a copy activity in a ForEach loop and I use the `item().<KeyName>` to access every item's value. In your case, you can use `item().id`, hopefully it helped you.

Comment: Yes, this worked, thank you Joseph!
New problem, my returned XML data contains CDATA format. According to Data Factory support, CDATA is not compatible with Data Factory. Have you heard or encountered this before?

Comment: Hi @user14031004, please see my updated answer. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.